# Recurring Events Lightning - Repeat field is not writable. How to use this field in custom lightning page?

Tags: lightning, activities, recursion

[image]I am trying to create a bulk action on recurring events. Isrecurrence2 field is not writable in the controller. 
How to create recurring events in custom lightning pages. 
The image is from my controller class. I want to set the field false intially.

Comment: Can you add relevant code snippet basically Minimum viable code to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Using visualforce page to create bulk recurring events. But I see this in the salesforce document "Lightning Experience event series are available in API versions 44.0 and later as read-only fields. Salesforce Classic recurring events are available in versions 7.0 and later."

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Yes I am able to build now with isrecurrence fields instead of isrecurrence2 . Thanks.